# is it possible to connect to an oracle database with pdo whilst using the one.com web host

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I am just wondering if it is possible to connect to an oracle database using PDO whilst using the one.com web host service.

```
$dsn = 'OCI:host= oracle access url;dbname= database name'; // define host name and database name
$username = 'username'; // define the username
$pwd ='password'; // password
$this->_connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $pwd);
```

Comment: If Oracle DB server allows connection form outside for that user and your host service has Oracle driver installed it should work.

Comment: Make sure to connect is over secure channel(ssh/ssl ...)

Comment: how can I test to see if one.com has oracle driver installed

Comment: Create file with `phpinfo();` and search for Oracle. Contract support.

Comment: I have just contacted one.com and there firewall blocks access from external source so that's why my oracle connection is not working.

Comment: That was easy.  Rule of thumb always start with service provider ;)

Comment: do you know any hosts that will allow oracle connection or do you think they all block oracle connection

Comment: Sorry have no idea. It is way to specific, your regular 8-10$ all you can eat hosting would not have it. For cheap I would check AWS/DigitalOcean/OpenShift/Heroku/GoogleApps/Microsoft Azure/Scaleway But you might need to do more maintenance yourself.